# How do I shuffle an ArrayList, but after shuffling specific indexes stay the same?

Tags: java, arraylist

In my `ArrayList`, every number has a color assigned to them based on their position within the `ArrayList`. Numbers in odd indexes are red, numbers in even indexes are blue, and numbers in indexes of multiples of 10 are black. I need to shuffle the list so that after the shuffle, the red numbers are still in odd indexes, the blue numbers are still in even indexes, and the black numbers are still in multiples of ten indexes. I know how to shuffle a whole list, but not specific things like this. How would I go about doing this?

Here is code for context:

```java
/* Term 2 Assignment 5 - Game Wheel */
/* GameWheel class*/
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class GameWheel
{
  // List of slices making up the wheel
  private List<Slice> slices;

  // Position of currently selected slice on wheel
  private int currentPos;


  /* Creates a wheel with 40 preset slices which are then randomized (keeping 
   * the color pattern the same).
   */
  public GameWheel()
  {
    slices = new ArrayList<Slice>();
    currentPos = 0;
    initGameWheel();
    scramble();
  }


  /* Spins the wheel by so that a different slice is selected. Return that 
   * slice (Note: the 20 slices following the current slice are more likely to 
   * be returned than the other 20).
   */
  public Slice spinWheel()
  {
    //spin power between range of 1-100 (inclusive)
    int power = (int)(Math.random()*100 + 1);
    int newPos = (currentPos + power) % slices.size();
    currentPos = newPos;
    return slices.get(currentPos);
  }


  /* Helper method for the constructor. Randomizes the positions of the slices 
   * that are in the wheel, but without changing the pattern of the colors 
   * (i.e. the red slices will still be at odd indices, the black slices at 
   * multiples of 10, and the blue slices at all other even indices).
   */ 
  private void scramble()
  {

  }


  // Helper method which initializes the slices in the wheel
  private void initGameWheel()
  {
    slices.add(new Slice("black", 8000));
    for (int i=1; i < 40; i++)
    {
      if (i%2 == 1)
        slices.add(new Slice("red", i*10));
      else if (i%10 == 0)
        slices.add(new Slice("black", i*200));
      else
        slices.add(new Slice("blue", i*100));
    }
  }


  // Returns the list of slices for this GameWheel
  public List<Slice> getSlices() {
    return slices;
  }
}
```

and here is how the slices are created:

```
/* Slice class*/
public class Slice
{
  private String color;
  private int prizeAmount;


  // Creates a slice with color c, and cash prize p
  public Slice(String c, int p) {
   color = c;
   prizeAmount = p;
  }


  // Returns the cash prize in dollars for this slice
  public int getPrizeAmount() {
    return prizeAmount;
  }


  // Returns the color of this slice as a string
  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }


  /* Returns a string representation of the slice in the following format: 
   * Color: red, prize amount: $50.
   */
  public String toString() {
    return "Color: " + color + ", Prize Amount: $" + prizeAmount;      
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Iterate through the List, and for each index determine if odd, even, or multiple of 10.  Then generate a random number < size of the List until that random number is also odd, even, or multiple of 10 (depending on the current index).  Swap the contents of the current index and the random index.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'easy' (as in, via an existing method like `Collections.shuffle`) way; you have to program this functionality yourself, but you can of course use some existing stuff to help you out.

One somewhat roundabout way is to 'deconstruct and reconstruct': Write a method that explodes a single list into 3 separate lists (1 for each colour), then shuffle those, then 'reconstruct' your three separate lists back into a single large list, using the obvious algorithm (if index divisible by 10, grab the next from the black list, otherwise if divisible by 2, grab from the blue list, otherwise, grab from the red list).

Another way is to just implement the shuffle algorithm yourself. For context, you're looking for the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which the implementation of `Collections.shuffle` also uses. The crucial things to know:

- To obtain a random number between 0 and N, call `.nextInt(n)` on an instance of `Random` (make a single instance, once, and keep reusing it). Do not use the common `(int) (Math.random() * n)`, which is subtly wrong (pigeonhole principle), and non-idiomatic java.
- fisher yates primarily involves going through the list from the start (index 0) to the *second to last element* (the one with index `list.size() -2`). For each element, swap it around with a uniform random chosen element that is itself or any element above it.

In other words, to shuffle `1,2,3,4,5`, we start at the 0th element (the 1), and pick any element, uniformly random, from itself and up to swap with. That's a choice of 5 elements, so we call `rnd.nextInt(5)` to figure it out. That random number could be 0, in which case 'you swap 1 with itself', meaning, it stays where it is (hey, shuffle means random; sometimes a card ends up in the same place in the pile after shuffling a deck of cards!). Then for the next element (the 2; at index 1), you pick any index from itself (so index 1) up to the end, so we call `rnd.nextInt(4)`, and so on.

For this exercise, the tricky bit is to figure out how many valid places 'above you' that you can swap with exist (that'd be the argument you pass to `rnd.nextInt(X)`), and how to translate the number that your nextInt invocation gives you with the index you now need to swap with.

Note that this algorithm works entirely in place; there is no need for any additional lists or arrays. A single temporary variable in order to enable the swap is all you need.

This sounds like homework, so I'm not going to pre-chew the answer for you. Hopefully this is enough for you to write it yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```java
public void shuffle(List<Slice> slices) {
    Map<String, Iterator<Slice>> slicesByColor = slices.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Slice::getColor)).entrySet().stream()
            .peek(e -> Collections.shuffle(e.getValue()))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().iterator()));

    for (int i = 0; i < slices.size(); i++) {
        Iterator<Slice> sliceIterator = slicesByColor.get(colorByIndex(i));
        slices.set(i, sliceIterator.next());
    }
}

private String colorByIndex(int index) {
    if (index % 2 == 1)
        return "red";
    else if (index % 10 == 0)
        return "black";
    else
        return "blue";
}
```

Output before:

```
[Color: black, Prize Amount: $8000, Color: red, Prize Amount: $10, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $200, Color: red, Prize Amount: $30, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $400, Color: red, Prize Amount: $50, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $600, Color: red, Prize Amount: $70, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $800, Color: red, Prize Amount: $90, Color: black, Prize Amount: $2000]
```

Output after:

```
[Color: black, Prize Amount: $2000, Color: red, Prize Amount: $90, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $800, Color: red, Prize Amount: $70, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $200, Color: red, Prize Amount: $10, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $400, Color: red, Prize Amount: $50, Color: blue, Prize Amount: $600, Color: red, Prize Amount: $30, Color: black, Prize Amount: $8000]
```

Answer (score -1):

I thik you could create 3 different list and shuffle them separately. After that recreate original list using shuffled lists:

```
public static List<Slice> shuffle(List<Slice> slices) {
    final int total = slices.size();
    List<Slice> red = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Slice> blue = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Slice> black = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;

    for (Slice slice : slices) {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            red.add(slice);
        else if (i % 10 == 0)
            black.add(slice);
        else
            blue.add(slice);
        i++;
    }

    Collections.shuffle(red);
    Collections.shuffle(blue);
    Collections.shuffle(black);

    Iterator<Slice> itRed = red.iterator();
    Iterator<Slice> itBlue = blue.iterator();
    Iterator<Slice> itBlack = black.iterator();
    slices.clear();

    for (int j = 0; j < total; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 1)
            slices.add(itRed.next());
        else if (j % 10 == 0)
            slices.add(itBlack.next());
        else
            slices.add(itBlue.next());
    }

    return slices;
}
```